# OPENCV Resize with accents and special characters, on Imgproc Java

Tags: java, opencv, resize

I'm doing the processing of files containing accents and special letters such as "º", so when you try to rotate the image or resize using Imgproc, the following error is issued:

```
String originalFileName = "D:\\ºteste\\teste4.jpg"
Mat image =  Highgui.imread(originalFileName);

int width = image.cols();
int height = image.rows();

double resizeRate = 0;

if (resizeToHeight <= 0) {
    resizeRate = ((resizeToWidth * 100.0) / width) / 100.0;
}

if (resizeToWidth <= 0) {
    resizeRate = ((resizeToHeight * 100.0) / height) / 100.0;
}

Mat resizeImage = new Mat();

if (resizeRate > 0) {
    Size sz = new Size(resizeRate * width, resizeRate * height);
    Imgproc.resize(image, resizeImage, sz);
} else {
    Size sz = new Size(resizeToWidth, resizeToHeight);
    Imgproc.resize(image, resizeImage, sz);
}
```

Message on Rotate

" OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0) in cv::warpAffine, file ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 3455 Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:3455: error: (-215) src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0 in function cv::warpAffine ] at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.warpAffine_2(Native Method) at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.warpAffine(Imgproc.java:9559) at juca.bastiao.Processor.autoRotate(Processor.java:258) at juca.bastiao.Processor.doResize(Processor.java:91) at juca.bastiao.Processor.resizeToFile(Processor.java:52) at juca.bastiao.Testes.main(Testes.java:30) "

Message on Resize

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in cv::resize, file ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 1834 Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:1834: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function cv::resize ] at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.resize_1(Native Method) at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.resize(Imgproc.java:8959) at juca.bastiao.Processor.doResize(Processor.java:111) at juca.bastiao.Processor.resizeToFile(Processor.java:52) at juca.bastiao.Testes.main(Testes.java:30)

Comment: Rotating and resizing is not the issue.  My guess is your call to  Highgui.imread(originalFileName) is failing because of the weird filenames and it's returning a Mat of size 0, 0.  I'd suggest either renaming the files without the special chars before executing this code, or look into how to escape them so HighGui can load them.

Comment: I'm change a base of api opencv in C++, modify Highgui and all classes to use _wfopen before it was fopen, and convert unicode to UF8.